# How do I close the "gap" in a smoothing curve in a polar plot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I feel like I'm making some very basic mistake here but search did not bring up anything, so here goes:

I am looking at saccades and have an angle and an amplitude per datapoint.

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(
  angle = runif(100,0,359),
  amplitude = runif(100,0,10)
  )

p <-
  ggplot() +
  stat_smooth(data=df, aes(y=amplitude, x=angle)) +
  coord_polar()
p
```

gives me this: (I am trying to get a closed ring without "end points".)

[image]

Comment: Do you want a vertical line between 0.11 and 0.04? Then you could perhaps add another row with angle = 361 (?) and y = 0.04 to your data frame. BTW: It's best practice to include a minimal reproducible example, which everyone can copy/paste/run to replicate the problem.

Comment: Without your data it's hard to say for sure, but this is probably happening because the smoothed values of `amplitude` are different at the two ends of the range. Just because the actual values are the same at the ends (are they?), doesn't mean the smoothed values will be the same. Try this without `coord_polar(..)` to see what I mean.

Comment: Edited to include minimal reproducible example.
I do not want a simple vertical line connecting the two endpoints but a kind of "ring smoothing", where the range between 259 and 0 degrees is treated like the range between 258 and 259. The idea is to demonstrate a continuous distribution. The current graph does not know that the two end points are not actually endpoints but points on a closed ring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gap in polar time plot - How to connect start and end points in geom\_line or remove blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589126/gap-in-polar-time-plot-how-to-connect-start-and-end-points-in-geom-line-or-rem)