# Plot time on x axis in R for Sleep Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I am trying to plot the nighttime sleep start timings, along with the average sleep start timing using ggplot. I basically have a bunch of columns of which the column of interest contains the POSIXct datetime objects. The sleep start timing spans a few months, so they all have different dates. I have tried the following code already:

```
# change all the datetimes to a single date + time
sleep$StartHMS <- format(sleep$StartDateTime, "%H:%M:%S")
sleep$StartHMS <- as.POSIXct(strptime(sleep$StartHMS, "%H:%M:%S"))
sleep %>% ggplot(aes(x=StartHMS)) + geom_histogram(position = "identity") + scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%I %p))
```

The issue with this is that there are two peaks in the histogram on each side since it starts at 4pm and ends around 4pm by default. I would like to start the histogram based on the min and max limits of the times available, and based on my data that would start around 8pm and end before 8am.

Do let me know if there's a better way to handle this data and plot this "time-series" because the histogram looks a bit off when it signals that there are many people sleeping around 4pm but that's not true, since running the following snippet says most people sleep sessions occur between 11pm (or 23 hours) and 12am (0 hours).

```
library(lubdridate)
sleep$SleepHour <- hour(sleep$StartDateTime)
sleep %>% ggplot(aes(x = SleepHour)) + geom_bar(position = "identity")
```

I would like to eventually plot the average time that people sleep as a geom_vline on the plot as well, and the x-axis needs to be in 12-hour time-format (AM/PM).

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Included some sample dummy data for StartDateTime here:

```
1  2021-03-20 23:47:30
2  2021-06-15 23:17:00
3  2021-06-21 22:35:00
4  2021-05-03 22:49:00
5  2021-06-23 00:51:00
6  2021-05-05 05:56:00
7  2021-05-22 22:34:00
8  2021-07-07 23:50:30
9  2021-04-14 22:29:30
10 2021-07-08 00:48:21
```

Comment: Could you provide at least some dummy data or just a subset where you could randomize the values?

Comment: @Marco_CH Please see my edit above!

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65705121/hours-scale-in-ggplot2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589126/gap-in-polar-time-plot-how-to-connect-start-and-end-points-in-geom-line-or-rem

Answer (score 0):

I think in the end the visualisation depends a bit on what statistics you're going to chose. If you decide that there might be autocorrelation, I think you really might want to look into time series analysis, and then simply taking an average per hour and plotting it can be very misleading if not plainly wrong.

To your question, I think using the hour information (by using lubridate) seems reasonable to me. You will simply need to convert it into a factor with correct factor levels, and tell ggplot not to drop unused levels.

Regarding 12h notation, you can just add labels to the factor. There might be clever functions out there that have those already included, but I don't know them.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
sleep <- read.table(text = "1  2021-03-20 23:47:30
2  2021-06-15 23:17:00
3  2021-06-21 22:35:00
4  2021-05-03 22:49:00
5  2021-06-23 00:51:00
6  2021-05-05 05:56:00
7  2021-05-22 22:34:00
8  2021-07-07 23:50:30
9  2021-04-14 22:29:30
10 2021-07-08 00:48:21")
names(sleep) <- c("rn", "date", "StartDateTime")

## I think it is a perfectly reasonable approach to just use the hour information, as you have done
sleep$StartHMS <- hour(hms(sleep$StartDateTime))
sleep %>% 
## change factor order, add the labels for 12h notation
  mutate(StartHMS = factor(StartHMS, levels = c(8:23, 0:7), labels = c(paste0(8:11, "am"), paste0(c(12,1:11), "pm"), paste0(c(12, 1:7), "am")))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=StartHMS)) + 
## because we're now dealing with a factor, we need geom_bar
  geom_bar() +
## don't drop unused factor levels
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

Comment: hi @tjebo is there anyway to easily represent the hour in 12-hour format instead of using numerals? that's the reason I didn't want to use lubridate's function to plot this but instead wanted a histogram. I also want a way to draw the median / average bed time on this same plot with the x axis only showing the range of bedtimes from 8pm to 8am (or whatever max and min values there are)

Comment: @Janet, you might have written the comment just before my update? Is the current labelling what you were imagining?

Comment: @janet regarding the limits - I think from my answer you should be able to come to the solution yourself? Regarding the geom_vline - you'll need to calculate the average count manually (returning a data frame), and then adding this as a geom_vline layer